# How to Use Condition and Drop Remaining Records Using JoltTransforms In Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to get the record using conditions and drop the remaining records using JolttransformJson Processor in Nifi, but I cannot achieve it please help me.

Conditions:

1. if the service has the value then print that record only and drop the remaining records.
2. if PublisherType has the value then print that record only and drop the remaining records.
3. if SubscriptionName has the value then print that record only and drop the remaining records.
4. if CompanyName has the value then print that record only and drop the remaining records.

Input:

```json
[ {
  "MeterCategory" : "Account",
  "MeterRegion" : "Switzerland-test",
  "PublisherType" : "Azure",
  "BillingAccountId" : "ce9f5",
  "SubscriptionName" : "CCL-Samuday",
  "ChargeType" : "usedreservation",
  "Region" : "Switzerland-test",
  "CloudProvider" : "AZURE",
  "isActive" : "Y",
  "isPublished" : "Y",
  "CompanyName" : "",
  "SubscriptionName0" : "",
  "DiscountTossp" : "15.00",
  "DiscountToCustomer" : "9.00",
  "Service" : "Account",
  "MeterCategory0" : "",
  "MeterSubCategory" : "",
  "PublisherType0" : ""
}, {
  "MeterCategory" : "Account",
  "MeterRegion" : "Switzerland-test",
  "PublisherType" : "Azure",
  "BillingAccountId" : "c39f5",
  "SubscriptionName" : "CCL-Samuday",
  "ChargeType" : "usedreservation",
  "Region" : "Switzerland-test",
  "CloudProvider" : "AZURE",
  "isActive" : "Y",
  "isPublished" : "Y",
  "CompanyName" : "",
  "SubscriptionName0" : "",
  "DiscountTossp" : "14.00",
  "DiscountToCustomer" : "8.00",
  "Service" : "",
  "MeterCategory0" : "",
  "MeterSubCategory" : "",
  "PublisherType0" : "Azure"
}, {
  "MeterCategory" : "Account",
  "MeterRegion" : "Switzerland-test",
  "PublisherType" : "Azure",
  "BillingAccountId" : "c3cf5",
  "SubscriptionName" : "CCL-Samuday",
  "ChargeType" : "usedreservation",
  "Region" : "Switzerland-test",
  "CloudProvider" : "AZURE",
  "isActive" : "Y",
  "isPublished" : "Y",
  "CompanyName" : "c3cf5",
  "SubscriptionName0" : "",
  "DiscountTossp" : "13.00",
  "DiscountToCustomer" : "7.00",
  "Service" : "",
  "MeterCategory0" : "",
  "MeterSubCategory" : "",
  "PublisherType0" : ""
}, {
  "MeterCategory" : "Account",
  "MeterRegion" : "Switzerland-test",
  "PublisherType" : "Azure",
  "BillingAccountId" : "c3cf5",
  "SubscriptionName" : "CCL-Samuday",
  "ChargeType" : "usedreservation",
  "Region" : "Switzerland-test",
  "CloudProvider" : "AZURE",
  "isActive" : "Y",
  "isPublished" : "Y",
  "CompanyName" : "",
  "SubscriptionName0" : "CCL-Samuday",
  "DiscountTossp" : "16.00",
  "DiscountToCustomer" : "4.00",
  "Service" : "",
  "MeterCategory0" : "",
  "MeterSubCategory" : "",
  "PublisherType0" : ""
} ]
```

Expected Output:

```json
[ {
  "MeterCategory" : "Account",
  "MeterRegion" : "Switzerland-test",
  "PublisherType" : "Azure",
  "BillingAccountId" : "ce9f5",
  "SubscriptionName" : "CCL-Samuday",
  "ChargeType" : "usedreservation",
  "Region" : "Switzerland-test",
  "CloudProvider" : "AZURE",
  "isActive" : "Y",
  "isPublished" : "Y",
  "CompanyName" : "",
  "SubscriptionName0" : "",
  "DiscountTossp" : "15.00",
  "DiscountToCustomer" : "9.00",
  "Service" : "Account",
  "MeterCategory0" : "",
  "MeterSubCategory" : "",
  "PublisherType0" : ""
}]
```

Note: In the Above Expected output why it prints that record only because the service Field is not empty?